# How to search and delete in registry a single REG_SZ value

Tags: windows-registry

How do I search an delete a `REG_SZ` value in System environment variables. 
For example, in System variables I have Variable named

```
LM_LICENSE_FILE= 123@abc;123@cde;123@fgh
```

I want to have a script to search for `123@cde` and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I search for and delete a REG_SZ value in System environment variables?

You can use `reg` to both find and delete registry entries.

You will need to know in which root the registry item you want to delete is stored.

> Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a
>   .REG file.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ...
>
> REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /v ValueName [/f]
>
> REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /ve [/f]  -- Remove the (default) value
>
> REG DELETE [ROOT]RegKey /va [/f]  -- Delete all values under this key
>
> ...
>
> Key:
>
> ROOT :
>
> HKLM = HKey_Local_machine (default)
>
> HKCU = HKey_current_user
>
> HKU  = HKey_users
>
> HKCR = HKey_classes_root
>
> ...
>
> ValueName : The value, under the selected RegKey, to edit.
>                  (default is all keys and values)

Source [reg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

---

#### Warning

The instructions above contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry.

However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.

For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete just a part of the value of a key using a batch script.
You *can* delete `LM_LICENSE_FILE`, which is a `REG_SZ`, but I don't think that's what you want.

You could use `reg add` to achieve what you're asking, though:

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /f /v "LM_LICENSE_KEY" /t REG_SZ /d "123@abc;123@fgh"`

will overwrite your existing `LM_LICENSE_FILE` variable with the new value of `123@abc;123fgh`.

- -`reg add "HKLM\...\Environment"` command, key
- `/f /v "LM_LICENSE_KEY` overwrite without prompting, value to act on
- `/t REG_SZ` datatype to add (default is `REG_SZ` so you could actually omit it here)
- `/d "123@abc;123@fgh"` data to be added